# Store arbitrary precision integer in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, gmp, arbitrary-precision, cryptocurrency

I have an application that needs to store cryptocurrency values to PostgreSQL database. The application uses arbitrary precision integers, and those I have to store to the database. What's the most efficient way to do that?

Why arbitrary precision? For two reasons:

1. For security. There shall never be an overflow.
2. For necessity. For example, Ethereum uses uint256 by default internally, and 1 Ether = 10^18 wei. So transactions will have a gigantic number of digits that has to be stored if accuracy is to be sought (which it's).

The best solution I came up with is to convert the number to a blob and store the number as bits in raw format. But I'm hoping there's a better way that's more suitable for a database.

EDIT:

The reason why I need this method for storing to be better is performance. I don't want to get into benchmarks and all this detail. That's why I'm keeping the question simple, or otherwise it'll get complicated. So the question is whether there's a proper way to do this.

Comment: I recently tried to store unicorn properties to postgresql and fancily failed with that. In the real and harsh world of turing complete computation, there's no such thin like _unicorn properties_ I had to learn.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I don't get your point. Are you saying that I'm pushing it too much?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html).

If you need efficiency but also depend on accurate values (which I would agree with), then you really should pre-define columns or different tables with specific presets using `decimal(precision, scale)`.

If your tests reveal that the standard data types are not performing good enough you might want to have a look at [bignum](https://github.com/beargiles/pg-bignum/blob/master/doc/bignum.md) and maybe others.